# What are the 7 kefullot in Tanya ch 3

Tags: tefilla, torah-study, mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism, chabad

BH

What are the 7 keffulot mentioned in Tanya ch 3 page?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure others can expound at length, but basically it's referring to the 7 middos (i.e. the lower sefiros) in the terminology of Sefer Yetzirah, listed [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Yetzirah_Gra_Version.4.2?lang=bi&with=Gra&lang2=en) (note the the Gra's translation into conventional kabbalistic terms). They're called "doubled" because they can each be expressed in two forms: "hard" (relating to judgement) and "soft" (relating to mercy). See [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30541&st=&pgnum=32&hilite=) for more detail.